What type and grit of sandpaper for sanding poplar door trim?
I just had new interior doors installed with poplar wood trim and doorstops. There's some wood "fuzz" (mostly on the sides and in between gaps I guess from the cuts, but also a bit rough on the surface). They will be painted.
What grit sandpaper should I use to smooth it out? And sanding sponge or actual sandpaper?



Those miters are a little disappointing. I don't see evidence of glue, either. I'd force as much wood glue in those joints as you can to hold them together. Use a good wood filler after that to get a level result. Nail placement is also poor. Use a set to sink them below flush before you do anything else.

Poplar tends to be fuzzy, just due to the nature of it's grain and softness. The paint or other topcoat will cover that, For paint I wouldn't bother sanding past 180, but that's me

@isherwood Thanks, I did see them using glue generally but not sure if they glued the miters. I think my photos are just unfortunate spots as most of the nails are below flush everywhere else, but will follow your advice and go around making sure they're all sunk in properly. Will consider adding some more glue as well before painters come. Thanks again!


I would probably use a sanding sponge since this is kinda curvy
I assume you're going to put some plastic wood or the like in the nail holes and maybe some of the bigger gaps
I would hit the dried plastic wood with 120 grit, but not too hard, then use maybe 220 all over. No need for getting finer than that if you are going to paint, it wouldn't be noticeable.


Maybe you and I have different ideas of what a sanding sponge is. The ones I have are far to rigid. Got a link to what you have in mind?

I would prime it or apply sanding sealer, then hit them with something in the neighborhood of 220. Sealing the wood will raise the grain as much as it's going to, and it'll prevent more fuzz when you sand.
With trim like that I wouldn't use any sort of block. That'll tend to flatten curves and edges too much. Use the compliance of your fingers to fit the various profiles.

You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. No need to follow up with comments.
